# Radio effect for videogame voicechat

Tags: microphone, distortion, game

I am currently modding a space game to implement ingame chat. Everything works fine, but I want to improve it by adding a distorting radio effect while the user is speaking. Sound quality should be worse the further away the communicators are. There shouldn’t be much delay. How do I add a distorting radio effect on the fly? What kind of waves or tricks do I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately I wrote a tutorial on this very subject. The DAW technology is a little older, but the techniques still apply.

https://www.greensideproductions.com.au/2013/01/04/creating-a-radio-effect-using-a-convolution-filter/

Comment: If I understand this right: The game has to load the Impulse response. When receiving a sound patch it has to apply the response to the sound patch using a convolution filter?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct, considering that the speech audio would be arriving in real-time.

Comment: and if you are worried about the speed of a convolution engine, check out this paper - W G Gardner worked out a way to do it using blocks much quicker than just raw convolution.

http://www.cs.ust.hk/mjg_lib/bibs/DPSu/DPSu.Files/Ga95.PDF